# Reliable Grids in Photoshop CC15 artboards

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grids

So I was/am really happy that Photoshop finally came out with artboards. It's great for a series of web ads and a whole host of other things, but what I use it for most is what it was intended for, which is mobile UI design.

I know that PS came out with their built-in grid system and there are others like GridGuide, which is my favorite, but with artboards, reliable guides are a thing of the past for me.

**TL/DR: Anyone know of a plugin or a way to get pixel perfect grids in artboards?**

Answer (score 1):

So I know that it seems like nobody cared about this question too much, but I have discovered the answer to this. I guess Grid Guide (or GuideGuide) has updated so that you can use their guides and they will snap to whatever dartboard you are in.

So that rules.

Comment: Never saw this question before now, but I think it was less about people caring about the question and more about people just not having a solution. I'm not sure what you expected when you asked this question. I'd personally message the extension dev and wait for them to update the it to work with the new feature. Probably going to be faster than someone building a new extension to challenge GuideGuide with added artboard support. I mean I guess it depends on the extension, but you won't find too many Grid extensions due to the fact that GuideGuide is pretty much as good as it can be.